# Bluetooth not turning on gnome settings Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: bluetooth

i recently installed ubuntu 20.04 lts in my hp omen 16 laptop. in the settings menu iam not able to toggle my bluetooth on it just goes automatically back to off. i tried some solutions but nothing worked
[this the output for systemctl | grep -i blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksAHD.png)
[output for rfkill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFdWz.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flZT6.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5fsq.jpg)

can anyone help me what the issue is ?

Comment: Please copy and paste text from terminal rather than posting images, please edit to include results for `lsusb`